# Is it necessary to pick the fittest in the selection part in genetic algorithm?

Tags: python, selection

I am new to genetic algorithm, maybe the question I am going to ask is so basic to you, but it really made me feel confused.

In the principle of genetic algorithm, we should pick the fittest as parents, and swap bits from the parents to generate thier children. After mutation, the selected parents and thier children will form a new population.

My question is that if we really need to pick the fittest as parents in each generation, and if we really need to form a new population using the fittest and their offspring? I found some example code about genetic algorithm made by others. In their code, when putting all function together, it seems like they pick all indivdiuals as parents, and use the parents to generate their offspring and finally all offspring are used to form a new population.

```
for i in range(0, population_size, 2):
        parent_1 = select_individual_by_tournament(population, scores)
        parent_2 = select_individual_by_tournament(population, scores)
        child_1, child_2 = breed_by_crossover(parent_1,parent_2)
        new_population.append(child_1)
        new_population.append(child_2)
```

But I feel confused about why in the example, why is the new population made of all offspring? In the principle of genetic algorithm, it seems like the new population is made of the selected parents with higher fitness score and their offspring.

I am not sure if my question is clear. Please let me know if my question is not clear and I am open to explain more on my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: `select_individual_by_tournament` implies (by its name) that a high-fitness individual is being selected, rather than a random individual.  Where are you getting the impression that all individuals are being chosen equally?

Comment: @Samwise Thank you for your reply. So is it possible that the fittest is selected more than once? and from the exmaple code, it really seems like all individuals have been chosen as parents.

Comment: There are only two parents in each iteration, and unless `select_individual_by_tournament` specifically prevents repeats, it seems very likely that some individuals will be picked as parents many times while others will never be picked.  Which ones get picked more often depends on how the "tournament" works.  If it were a purely deterministic fitness function you'd end up with the same individual getting picked every time, but I suspect there's a random element in there.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  It sounds like you already understand how this works.

Comment: @Samwise I'm so sorry for not making my qustion clear.  My question is that  why only offspring is appended to new_population in the example code? According to the principle of GA, the new_population should be made of  the selected parents and their offspring in the last generation. The way the example code did seems like disagree with the principle of GA.

Comment: GA doesn't require that you include the parents in the next generation.  Many organisms in the real world die as soon as they produce offspring, and they evolve nonetheless.  :)

Comment: @Samwise whether or not there is a possibility that the fitness score of offspring will be less than that of thier parents?

Comment: There's a possibility, but the core concept of GAs is that the trend will be toward improved fitness over time.  If children are more likely than not to have *worse* fitness than their parents then evolution is difficult (and you might need to rethink how your simulated genome works).